# Web-Scraping Roblox API with bs4 and requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, roblox

I want to get only the "Sales" and the value of it printed out in console.

**Roblox Website**

https://api.roblox.com/Marketplace/ProductInfo?assetId=6971062344

**Python file**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

ID = 6971062344

url = f'https://api.roblox.com/Marketplace/ProductInfo?assetId={ID}'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
sales = soup.find()

print(sales)
```

Comment: Your URL is an API, you don't have to use BeautifulSoup. `requests` by it self is sufficient.

Comment: alright, but how do i then get only the sales value from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is an API that returns a `JSON`. `requests` by itself is sufficient to have your desired data. Here is an example how you can get your data:

```
import requests


url = 'https://api.roblox.com/Marketplace/ProductInfo?assetId=6971062344'
data = requests.get(url).json()
sales = data['Sales']
# 0
```